# Using PHP to execute ssh/command line properly

Tags: php, shell, ssl, exec

So I need a bit of help in regards to ssh/command lines being run from php.

Out of the gate - yes exec is enabled on the server - its our own dedicated box

The setup. I have created a script that uses cpanel's api to create sub domains
for a particular account. That's all fine and dandy and everything works as expected.
Now - we have a wildcard SSL installed as well.

The long and short of it is this. Under the present conditions if you pulled up:
https://user.domain.com you would only see the top root directory for the account,
NOT the directory it should be in. But if you use it without the https - it does what
it should. Now it's a dedicated box with HostGator and they had this script they
installed for me to do what needs to be done - and that works as expected.

The script HostGator installed is located at:
/var/cpanel/userdata/account/mdssl

So the line they gave me to run the script and do what it should do is as follows:

./mdssl clone domain.com user.domain.com

So my question is - because I have never really worked with shell stuff 
inside of php, would the following line be a workable example of how to execute the script?

shell_exec('/var/cpanel/userdata/account/mdssl clone domain.com user.domain.com');

or do I just need the exec command? And should the opening line be any different?
I just need to tap that line using php and pass the 'user' field to it and have the 
script do its thing to clone the setup for the SSL so that the wildcard features work
properly and the users account lands in the proper directory it should.

Any insight is appreciated! :)

Thank you very much.

Comment: i went back into my account and clicked on each question and then click on 'yes' to was this helpful. Is that NOT the proper way to do it?

Comment: @MrTechie You click the Checkmark next to a specific answer that helped you solve the issue, the checkmark turns green and then the answer is accepted.

Comment: @MrTechie  Do you know which configuration in httpd.conf is pointing the user subdomain to the wrong directory?  I wonder if there is an easier fix than having to run this script for each account to copy their directory.  The SSL vhost should be able to point to public_html just as the regular vhost for their account does so I think there may be an easier way.

Comment: @drew010 - thats for the instructions on how to accept answers, those are done. I am not sure about the httpd.conf that is causing the issue, but I do know this. in the /var/cpanel/userdata/account/ directory there is a file for the ssl. it's like this: domain.com_SSL, and when I nano'd into it the opening line has a document root = /home/user/public_html - but because that is for the 'main' account holding the wildcard ssl - that is correct. BUT, because the end results needs to be: /var/cpanel/userdata/account/user.domain.com_SSL which is what mdssl does - it clones domain.com_SSL

Comment: So I need the proper way using php to be able to get to that mdssl file and pass a single variable (user) to it, and have it create the file. I saw that maybe passthru would work - but I need to know how to set the proper path to be able to do it. Like I said, shell/ssh and php are new to me.

Comment: @MrTechie Ok maybe in that case using it is necessary then.  `shell_exec` should work fine, or even `exec`.  You can construct your command using variables like `$cmd = "mdssl clone $domain $user.$domain";` and then pass the command variable to one of the functions.  The only issue may be that the user running PHP doesn't have permission to manipulate the files in question.

Comment: @drew010 - the path doesn't need to change? Just ./mdssl is it? And then simply do shell_exec($cmd);? The user account has full root access to the server, just an fyi.

Comment: @MrTechie You may need to specify the full path to the script assuming it isn't in your shell path when using shell_exec.  I just wrote that for brevity.  For sanity's sake, when you test your script, echo the contents of `get_current_user();` to make sure the PHP script is running as the privileged user and not apache.

Comment: @drew010 - after echoing get_current_user() (because this resides on that account) it provides me with a different user. When I login as that user and try to go to that directory it gives me: 
-jailshell: cd: var/cpanel/userdata/account: Permission denied. So it looks like I am going to need to be able to run this line as a root user from within the account. Any thoughts?

Comment: Depending on your OS and what user the script is running as, you may need to use `sudo` to run the command.  This still isn't ideal if the script is running as a generic user which all other accounts use, then they would have sudo access as well.  Are you running the PHP script from the browser or shell?

Comment: @drew010 - The script is going to run from php to tap that mdssl and at that point, it's probably going to be under a cron script setup that has the bash tag at the top of it.

Answer (score 0):

I've only used [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) or [`system()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php)

They're always tricky and tend not to behave as expected.

I would start off with

```
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

exec('/var/cpanel/userdata/account/mdssl clone domain.com user.domain.com', $output);

var_dump($output);
```

See what the output says or if a PHP error is occurring.

You may also need to escape out of the current directory of whatever default you're in with `../` and make sure `apache` user has access to mdssl (or whatever user your system uses).  You may need to `sudo` it.